# CSS3: Calculate difference between (left + scale3d) and (transition3d + scale3d)

Tags: html, css, scale

Why is there a difference between (`scale3d` and `left`) and (`scale3d` and `translate3d`)? And how do I calculate the difference between them?

See example: [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/uhibog/2/)

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, .3);
    border-radius:7px;
    font-size:20px;

    -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
}
#t1 {
    left: 200px;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 1);
}
#t2 {
    top: 200px;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 1) translate3d(200px, 0, 0);
}
```

and the simple HTML:

```
<div id="t1">scale3d and left</div>
<div id="t2">scale3d and transition3d</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS3 Transforms alter the local coordinate system. When you scale an element you're also scaling any translations applied to that div. Here - if you change the translate to 400px - you get the same result (reversing the effect of the scale).

You can check what transformations are currently applied to an element by using getComputedStyle().